# highstock 1.3 disable navigator dragging redraw

Tags: highcharts, navigator

Is there a way to disable the constant redrawing that occurs in highstock 1.3 when dragging the navigator or the navigator handles?

In 1.25 when you move the navigator or pan the chart by dragging, 1 redraw event is fired once you release the mouse. 
In 1.3 multiple redraws are fired while you are dragging the navigator/panning the chart.

I would like to know if I can return the behaviour of the chart in 1.3 to the way it works in 1.25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the automatic redrawing when scrolling, we have a new option in the highstock 1.3 api:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.liveRedraw

```
scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false 
}
```

This fixes the problem.