# Highstock 1.3 afterSetExtremes throttling

Tags: highcharts

I updated Highstock.js to 1.3 and noticed that the `afterSetExtemes` event fires on every drag event as opposed to dragend/mouseup. I'm updating the main series via ajax but now this causes hundreds of ajax calls to fire simultaneously. I can't seem to find the setting to prevent this. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Can you show some demo ?

Comment: Funny enough, their own updated demo exposes that problem. If you move it around enough, you'll see in the network debugger panel that hundreds of calls get queued up. Try moving the handles around quickly and you'll see them jump around too.  http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced the same issue.

The option you are looking for is:

```
scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false 
}
```

Check out my question which I posted the answer on:
[highstock 1.3 disable navigator dragging redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417426/highstock-1-3-disable-navigator-dragging-redraw/15702812#15702812)